# `loadURL` in Electron has error "window.require is not a function" only this website

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

NOTE: Electron 17.0.1

I'm so confuse about to use the `win.loadURL` function in Electron.
For main purpose, to create a dark theme for chat application.
I want to loadURL in Electron and inject CSS to change to dark theme.

BUT when I use `loadURL` and then run Electron app.
It will show an error `"window.require is not a function"`
and `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'instance')"`

here is my code:

```js
// main.js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
const path = require("path");

function createWindow() {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1200,
    height: 800,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
    },
  });

  win.webContents.openDevTools();
  win.loadURL("https://seatalkweb.com/");
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow();

  app.on("activate", () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
      createWindow();
    }
  });
});

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});
```

```js
// preload.js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const replaceText = (selector, text) => {
    const element = document.getElementById(selector);
    if (element) element.innerText = text;
  };

  for (const type of ["chrome", "node", "electron"]) {
    replaceText(`${type}-version`, process.versions[type]);
  }
});
```

and this is an error:
[image]
[image]

I do not know why it has an error only this website when open in electron? (no problem if open in chrome)
this website is `https://seatalkweb.com/`
and it fine if I use other URL instead (such as google.com, facebook.com, etc.)

How can I fix it ?
and could somebody can explain me about this problem ?

Comment: Presumably the JavaScript on the remote website you're loading assumes a Node.js environment but by default Electron now disable `nodeIntegration` which is most likely the reason for that error. You should not enable `nodeIntegration` as it gives that website access to Node.js APIs which they can use to read/write files on the user machine. Also context isolation is enabled by default so your preload script is likely to not work in the way you think it will.

Answer (score -1):

Seems weird like a `require` is called is your page but it's maybe an Electron call du to the LoadUrl... If it's a `require` problem you may need to activate the Node integration..

```js
const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1200,
    height: 800,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
      nodeIntegration: true
    },
  });
```

If it's not from Electron Node integration, then in may be a problem in your web page script.

Comment: Electron document suggest me to not set `nodeIntegration` to `true`. By the way I try to set it `true` but it still not working.

Comment: Then it may be more a problem on the given web page script..